# Why is curl returning 'not found' error while querying TMDB API with my API key?

Tags: curl

I took a tmdb api key (as it is free) for my educational purposes. I tried to get the data using curl from my terminal but it is showing that it is "not found". when I use the same link in a browser it is giving me information. I don't understand why curl is unable to "get" data.

The code I have used

```
curl -X GET https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=<API KEY>&query=Jack+Reacher
```

The reply that my terminal is giving

```
zsh: no matches found: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=<API KEY>
```

I have used other methods like wget. It was also showing the same. What should I do?

Comment: `&` has a special meaning in the command line, add quotes around your URL